# Regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regex for allowing only numbers + following characters (`+`, , `(` ,`)` )

I have done this :

```
^-{0,1}\d+$
```

But this is taking only numbers ..how we can write it for the charecters as well?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are the allowed forms? `+1`, `-1`, `(1)`? You can try `/^[-+()]?\d+$/` but you need to elaborate.

Comment: allowed numerics and +,spaces,(,)

Comment: Can the string be nothing but spaces, or `++++` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^[0-9-.+ ()]+$
```

Comment: How will this work..? It needs escape characters before special characters to make it work..like `"(" should be "\("`

Comment: @Vishal Not inside a character group

Comment: @VishalSuthar, you are only partly correct. Normal regex special characters loose their special meaning inside a character class. So, no need to escape e.g. a `(`. But there are new special characters for character classes, like the `-` as range operator. It will work here in this case without escaping (special case directly after a range), but in general, to avoid wrong ranges the dash should be escaped or put it on the start or end of the class.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the solution:

```
^[0-9\+\s\(\)]+$
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?323ka)**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a character class. You can define one with square brackets `[]`. Then just add all those characters, ranges or predefined shorthand classes to your character class.

```
[-+\d() ]
```

Such a character class will then match exactly one character out of the class members.

You may want to read more details about character classes on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or a real brief overview about basic regex features on my [blog post "What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)"